# NPM can't install appjs

Tags: node.js, npm, appjs

I have no idea what's going on here, so I figure it'd be better to just show rather than tell:

[image: Screenshot of error in Windows console]

I'm using Windows 7 and have installed Node.js using the installer.

Comment: Have you tried running it as administrator?

Comment: Yes, just did - same crap.

Comment: Looks like a corrupted `.npm` folder. Have you tried `$ npm cache clean`?